# How to fill 100% of the viewport when scaling down the webpage?

Tags: css, viewport

I have a webpage which is scaled down from 1 to 0.5 depending on the browser window size. Now on my page I have a little square inside a div, which I want to be centered on the whole page. So what I need to achieve is giving the div a width which fills 100% of the browser width. Using something like `width:100%` will not give the result I am looking for as it will set the width to the width of the browser window (i.e. 1600px). But as my page is scaled down, 1600px will be too small. So then I tried to do something like:

```
$square.css('width', (viewportWidth*negscale) + 'px');
```

where `negscale` is `3-(2*scale)`, so for example if I scale the page to 0,5 (which means it is half the size), `negscale` would be 2, so the square would have a width of 2 times the width of the viewport.
Now the weird part is that for 0,5 and for 1 it works perfectly fine, but for every scale in between the width of the div is somehow too big. I really can't think of any reason why this could be.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong or has another way of finding out how wide the div has to be to fill 100% of the viewport?

Comment: Without looking at some code, I guess that this has something do do with the fact that scale affects both x and y dimensions, while width affects only the x dimension. 

Can you provide a jsfiddle example or some other code to look at?

Comment: I will try doing it later, but how can the y dimension be of any regard when only the width is important? I mean with 0,5 and 1 it works fine.